# How to create a standalone custom library that uses a non-stanalone third party library in Angular?

Tags: angular, libraries, ngx-bootstrap

I have a custom library that uses another third-party library (ngx-bootstrap) which is not a collection of standalone components, services, etc... and requires importing Modules. This custom library is working well exporting a module that imports the needed modules from ngx-bootstrap.

I'd like to know if it's possible to make my library fully standalone, or I need keep exporting that module.